# Why can't I addEventListener after removeEventListner has been used?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

On [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) I read " An EventListener can never be invoked after being removed," but I would assume this doesn't mean you can't add it again (that wouldn't make sense). This is a simplified example of what I am doing, so IF there is a minor syntax error in the example, it can be ignored (unless a syntax error MUST be the problem).

```
function OhYeah(el){
    this.stuff = [];

    this.stuff.push(new Obj(el));
}

OhYeah.prototype = {
    removeStuff: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.stuff.length; i++){
            this.stuff[i].selfDestruct(); // removes listener
        } 

        this.stuff = [];
    },

    addStuff: function(el) {
        this.stuff.push(new Obj(el)); // should add listener on creation of Obj
    }
}

function Obj(el) {
    // some other properties not shown that can be different even if the same "el" is used to create a new Obj

    this.domOBJ = document.getElementById(el);

    this.domOBJ.addEventListener("input", this, false);
}


Obj.prototype = {
    ...

    handleEvent: function(){
        ...
    },
    selfDestruct: function() {
        this.domOBJ.removeEventListener("input", this, false);
    }
}

var obj = new OhYeah("demo"); // adds listener successfully

obj.removeStuff(); // removes listener successfully
obj.addStuff("demo") // you would think this would add the listener, BUT it does NOT
```

Comment: `.addEventListener("input", this` <--- this?????? HUH????

Comment: @epascarello—it works because *Obj* has a *handleEvent* method on its prototype. The handler will call that when handling the event, see the spec for the [*W3C DOM 2 Events EventListener interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener), updated in the [*DOM 3 Events spec*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-EventListener).

Comment: [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) doesn't say "*…can never be invoked after being removed*" any more. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code had some syntax errors. Since you've fixed those but apparently the code doesn't work then it must be elsewhere, the following works:

```
<input id="demo">

<script>
function OhYeah(el){
    this.stuff = [];
    this.stuff.push(new Obj(el));
}

OhYeah.prototype = {
    removeStuff: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.stuff.length; i++){
            this.stuff[i].selfDestruct(); // removes listener
        } 
        this.stuff = [];
    },

    addStuff: function(el) {
        this.stuff.push(new Obj(el)); // adds listener on creation of Obj
    }
}

function Obj(el) {
    this.domOBJ = document.getElementById(el);
    this.domOBJ.addEventListener("input", this, false);
}

Obj.prototype = {
    handleEvent: function(){
          console.log('input...');
        }
    },
    selfDestruct: function() {
        this.domOBJ.removeEventListener("input", this, false);
    }
  }

  var obj = new OhYeah("demo"); // adds listener successfully

  obj.removeStuff();   // removes listener successfully
  obj.addStuff("demo") // adds  listener successfully

</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sawsqtkn/1/) showing it works.

Note that this works because of the *handleEvent* property of *Obj.prototype*. See [*W3C DOM 3 Events Specification, eventListener interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-EventListener).

Comment: But wouldn't it be correct to pass the `addEventListener` function an object with the property `handleEvent`? See the section about using `handleEvent` on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Ok, now I see what you're trying to do. Gimme some time.

Comment: Also note that adding the listener and removing BOTH work the first time so using `handleEvent` as a property of the `Obj` and then passing the event listener `this` does work.

Comment: @cojomojo—I've pasted working code. Commenting out the last two lines, then revealing them one at a time shows they work to add, remove, then add the listener again. BTW, I wasn't aware you could do this with native objects, cool. ;-)

Comment: Just learned it myself not too long ago as well. Ok, its working. Gonna have to look at my actual code and examine the differences.